# Is there any compelling reason for me to un-static this method?

Tags: android

I have this SaveCheckedStateToDB() function:

```
public class oDaA_DBUtils {

    // TOOD: Perhaps this should not be static, and I should force callers to instantiate the class first?
    public static void SaveCheckedStateToDB(int AOptionSelected, String id, boolean AToggledOn)
    {
      //
    }
}
```

...that I changed to "static" after getting static about calling it from here prior to adding the "static" keyword:

```
            cbOnDemand.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
            @Override 
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                // Contact id is a string?
                oDaA_DBUtils.SaveCheckedStateToDB(oDaA_Consts.ALERT_ON_DEMAND, id, isChecked);
                }
            });
```

Now it compiles, but is that a "wrong" way of working? Should I remove the "static" appendage/decoration and force callers to instantiate the class prior to calling SaveCheckedStateToDB()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to un-static it. This method does not need any of the "state" of its class, as it's obviously a utility class, so it *should* be static.

If it's indeed a utility class, you should enforce it by forbidding instantiation: make the default constructor private:

```
private oDaA_DBUtils {
    // no instances allowed!
}
```

Also, it's good practice to follow the Java naming standards: capitalized camelcase for class names, and uncapitalized camelcase for methods. This will help you in the long run to see what you're doing at first glance when looking at your code.

```
public class OdaaDbUtils
public static void saveCheckedStateToDb(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

One very good reason to avoid many static method is for testability. Static methods usually make unit testing very difficult and painful. Using class instances with interfaces (for example in combination with dependency injection), is usually a good option. However, there are situations, such as factories and utility classes, where static methods and enum classes are good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

you can use static functions, where

1. you don't need the non-static class members or methods in that function.
2. when this function is somehow a factory function, and you are trying to create and return an object of class. ( so there is no object to call it! )

when you are writing a static function be aware that it doesn't inherit. 
so it is not something that you decide about it when you are coding! it is an issue of first analysis and modeling of system. and if you use many static methods, whole OO concepts will be ruined!

I need to know more about the mechanism of this function and its class for better answer.
but any way you said the code complies, so there is no member vars in that function, and if there is no inheritance or polymorphism issue in your system, you can make it static.